# How to search between dates ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have this query :

```
SELECT * FROM tabl1

WHERE
(
     created_time BETWEEN 
                         DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02') 
                         AND
                         DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02')+INTERVAL 1 MONTH

     AND

     DAY(NOW()) > 1
)
OR
(
   created_time BETWEEN
                       DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02')
                       AND
                       DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02')-INTERVAL 1 MONTH    
   AND
   DAY(NOW()) = 1
)
```

this query will return the columns that created last month,
but the month start at day number 2 and end at the second day of the next month !

so it will return :

```
3.3.2015
2.3.2015
```

but it will not return

```
1.3.2015
```

How to write the query with better way ?

Comment: I can see that you have specifically written DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-02') , try replacing the 02 with 01 and check.

Answer (score -1):

Always do this:

```
where datefield >= YourStartDate
and datefield < TheDayAfterYourEndDate
```

Dateformat returns strings and is for display purposes only.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can write the query like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabl1 
WHERE DATE >= '2015-02-02 00:00' AND DATE_2 <= '20015-03-02 23:59'
```

Comment: I didn't understand the ' -1 ', the essence is like that, but you need to improve it